# Why condition_variable in this code blocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I'm new to condition variables and I wonder why this piece of code blocks after counter variable is equal to 99? 
Deleting the for loop and putting "counter += 99" instead makes the code work, does it have anything to do with sleep_for? Thanks for help :)

```
#include<thread>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>
#include <iostream>
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;
int counter = 0;

void foo() {
    std:: unique_lock<std::mutex>lck{ mtx };
    //counter += 99;
    for (; counter < 100; counter++) {
        std::cout << counter << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    }
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    std::thread th(&foo);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lck{ mtx };
        cv.wait(lck, [] {
            return counter == 99;
        });
    }

    std::cout << "!!!!!" << std::endl;
    th.join();
}
```

Comment: Also `counter` needs to be atomic

Comment: @RichardCritten No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let's add some annotation to your code:

```
void foo() {
    std:: unique_lock<std::mutex>lck{ mtx };
    // counter == 0
    for (; counter < 100; counter++) {
        ...
    }
    // counter == 100
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_one(); // <== notify here
}
```

We're looping until `counter == 100`, at which point we notify `cv`. However, we are waiting for `counter == 99`, which is not true at the point when it gets notified. The only way for `wait()` to return in your code is for a spurious wakeup to happen right at the last iteration of the loop.

Perhaps you meant to loop while `counter < 99`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that :)!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<thread>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>
#include <iostream>
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;
int counter = 0;

void foo() {
    std:: unique_lock<std::mutex>lck{ mtx };
    //counter += 99;
    for (; counter < 100; counter++) {                                // B
        std::cout << counter << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    }
    lck.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();                                                  // C
}
```

At the end of your loop (**B**), counter has a value of 100.

```
int main() {
    std::thread th(&foo);
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lck{ mtx };
        cv.wait(lck, [] {
            return counter == 99;                                     // A
        });
    }

    std::cout << "!!!!!" << std::endl;
    th.join();
}
```

Your condition to wake up the thread running `main()` is that `counter` has a value of 99 (**A**).

Because you call `unlock()` after your loop is finished (**C**), the value of `counter` is 100. Your `std::condition_variable` will only wake up its the waiting thread when the value of `counter` is 99 (**A**). Therefore, unless there is a spurious wakeup in the waiting thread when `counter` has a value of 99 (which would cause the `std::condition_variable`'s condition to evaluate to `true`), your waiting thread will be stuck waiting forever.

You can fix this by simply changing the `std::condition_variable`'s predicate as follows:

```
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lck{ mtx };
        cv.wait(lck, [] {
            return counter == 100; // CHANGED TO 100 FROM 99.
        });
    }
```

Or (the exclusive kind) by changing the condition in your `for()` loop as follows:

```
for (; counter < 99; counter++) { // `counter < 100` is now `counter < 99`
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped a lot ! :)

Comment: You should accept either @Barry's answer or mine if your question has been answered.